# Change background color of TEXT only in Jumbotron using the Illdy theme for Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Is it possible to change the color of just a block of text in Jumbotron using the CSS customizer for the theme in Wordpress? I don't mean to change the background color of the entire jumbotron section, jut od TEXT (like highlighting it with semi-transparent white so the text can be better seen against the background image I have).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code or the link of your wordpress site and tell us exactly what TEXT need to be highlighted with semi-transparent white? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the support... http://welldoneremodel.com 

I need to make the words on the top portion have a light gray background for readability. Starting with "CLEAN" then ending in "Remodel Your Home" above the main buttons.

The only jumbotron code I have is to hide sections I don't need:

#about .skill {
    display: none!IMportant;
}
footer .container {
    display: none!important;
}

.bottom-footer .container {
    display: block!important;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 0px!Important;
}

.bottom-footer {
    margin-top: 0px!Important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Below code can change the text background color.

```
#header.header-front-page .bottom-header .section-description {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: lightgray; /* Add this line */
    /* background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); */ /* transparent white */
}

/* Add this style */
.bottom-header .container .row .col-sm-12 {
    background-color: lightgray;
    /* background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); */ /* transparent white */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but it turned the background not semi-transparent, but flat gray. 
Any changes to suggest? Thanks again.

Comment: transparent white `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` transparent gray `background-color: rgba(211,211,211,0.5);`